# htaccess 301 redirect for non friendly urls

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm having trouble finding something to work to this problem.
I have a rewrite rule in my htaccess that does the rewrite for the url when I acces it directly :

```
RewriteRule [a-zA-Z0-9_]+-c([0-9]+)-p([0-9]+)$   list.php?id=$1&page=$2   [QSA]
```

So `www.domain.com/list-of-products-c1-p1` works fine.

But so does `www.domain.com/list.php?id=1&page=1` which I don't want!

is there any way to 301 redirect this unfriendly url to the seo-friendly url with htaccess?

Thanx!

Comment: I didn't get a relevant answer so I decided to doit with a PHP function and call it on top if the page


`function redirect301pages($page) {
  $mystring = curPageURL();
  if ($page=='list.php') {
  $unf =  strpos($mystring, $page);
  if (isset($unf) && !empty($unf)) {
   if (isset($_GET['page'])) $page=$_GET['page']; else $page=1;
   if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    #$link=get your link here
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");    
    header("Location: ".$link.""); 
    }
   }
  } //list.php
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([\d]+)&page=([\d]+)$
RewriteRule ^ list-of-products-c%1-p%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: "list-of-products" its dynamic based on id. So it can be list-of-apples for id=1 or list-of-books for id=2